# In Angular Seed project, what is point of index-async.html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been getting started with Angular JS and using it as a front-end to integrate
with a Play Framework POC. I've already worked through the tutorial.

I cloned my front end from the seed project on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/). It has an `app/index.html`
(which I'm using as my main page) and an `app/index-async.html`. What is
the point of the latter? Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The two files are interchangeable, and you can use either one to build your application. `index-async.html` loads scripts asynchronously, which might give you a faster bootstrap time. `index.html` loads scripts synchronously, which is often a bit slower, but the intention is that the code is easier to understand for someone learning to use the framework.

To read more about asynchronous bootstrapping, check out the docs here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: Sure it's faster, but does it make a difference on how the rest of the application is coded. Or is it just the first page that changes?

Comment: My assumption is that it won't change much. The page will fully load, which means that any {{}} in the index page will be rendered before angular gets bootstrapped.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts, however, I think as for the example or starter it's bit of confusing to understand.